# When I create a React application in the terminal, I get a command error. Any advice?

Tags: reactjs, bash

When I try to run `create-react-app my-app` I get the following error:

`zsh: command not found: create-react-app`

Am I missing something regarding `npm` / `path`?

Comment: Have you installed it globally? `npm i -g create-react-app`

Comment: Why do you use `bash` tag?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response. I tried that along with `npm config set prefix /usr/local` followed by `sudo npm install -g create-react-app` and it finally worked!